# In django which is the best way to make a slideshow of background images?

Tags: django

I have three images in my urls file that randomly become my homepage background

but what is the best way to constantly make the home page change background image every 5 seconds from the from the three pictures specified in the urls file?

Whats the best way to do it?

---

Django

```
def homePage(request):
    images = ['RockTop', 'TheThree', 'ThreeBoys']
    background_image = 'static/' + images[random.randint(0,2)] + '.JPG'
    return render(request, 'homePage.html', {'background_image': background_image})
```

Comment: you want background image to change every 5 seconds while you're looking at the page? or every 5 seconds the server starts serving a different random background image?

Answer (score 1):

i would render all images to frontend and slide with jquery.

something like: (you need to adjust variables names accordingly, these are almost pseudo ones)

```
{% for im in all_images %}
   <img src="im.url" id="im_{{ forloop.counter }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

jquery:

```
var random_im_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // random number between 1 - 3
var background_image = 'url(' + $('#im_' + random_im_id).attr('src') +  ')';

$('body').css('background-image', background_image);
```